# Fast, low-memory, constant key-value database supporting concurrent and random access reads

Tags: multiprocessing, key-value, key-value-store, multiprocess

I need an on-disk key-value store, not too big or distributed.  The use case is as follows:

- The full DB will be few Gbs in size
- Both key and value are of constant size
- Its a constant data base. Once the entire database is written I don't need to write any more entries (or write very infrequently)
- Keys will be accessed in unpredictable order
- **Supporting concurrent reads by multiple processes is a must**.
- Have to be very fast because the readers will be **accessing millions of keys in a tight loop**. So it should be as close as possible to being as performant as looping over an associative array (`STL's std::map` say)
- Ideally it should allow one to set how much RAM to use, typically it should use a few hundreds of Mbs
- Written in C or C++. An existing python extension will be a big plus, but iI can add that on my own

So `cdb` and `gdbm` look like good choices, but just wanted to know if there are more suitable choices. Pointers to relevant benchmarks or even relevant anecdotal evidence will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi whoever suggested edits, I somehow lost them while trying to accept them. If there is a way to recover your changes, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

What database did you end up using?

If you like cdb and you need > 4 GB database, please have a look at mcdb, which is originally based on cdb, plus some performance enhancements and the addition of support for 4 GB+ constant databases.

https://github.com/gstrauss/mcdb/

Python, Perl, Lua, and Ruby extensions are provided.  mcdb is written in C and uses mmap under the hood and so easily supports lock-free concurrent reads between threads and between processes.  Since it is backed by a memory-mapped file, pages are mapped in from disk as needed and memory is effectively constant even as the number of processes accessing the database increases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at bdb? It sounds like a good use of BDB.

Comment: yes. I meant gdbm to stand for the dbm and bdb implementations

Comment: Ah, Ok. I figured you just meant gdbm by that. There's of course the problem wit gdbm that it's GPL, so it could cause your software to be GPL.

Comment: My bad should have made that clear. GPL isnt a problem for me at all. If they are giving something for free, which they arent obligated to, they are entitled to the terms they want.

Comment: I don't really have a problem with it, in fact I like what they do, it just CAN be a problem if your program isn't intended to be GPL or compatible. The powers that be sometimes do not like that.

Answer (score 0):

i like hamsterdb because i wrote it :)

http://www.hamsterdb.com

- frequently used with database sizes of several GBs
- keys/values can have any size you wish
- random access + directional access (with cursors)
- concurrent reads: hamsterdb is thread safe, but not yet concurrent. i'm working on this.
- if your cache is big enough then access will be very fast (you can specify the cache size)
- written in c++
- python extension is available, but terribly outdated; will need fixes

if you want to evaluate hamsterdb and need some help then feel free to drop me a mail.

Comment: looks interesting. Have you benchmarked it against the db, dbm family for read speeds. I dont need multi-threading though, only the ability to open it for reads from multiple process. The latter is mandatory.

Comment: i have benchmarked against berkeleydb, and in most of the benchmarks hamsterdb is much faster and scales better. (in a few others bdb is a bit faster). I have not tested against gdbm. Btw - thread safety is for multiple threads, not multiple processes. hamsterdb locks the file exclusively, and there's NO single writer/multiple reader support. For this i have an embedded http-based client/server model. Sorry - i missed that requirement when reading your original post.

Comment: Oh then its bit of a bummer because I cannot afford the http overhead. Thanks for getting back.

Comment: in that case i think only Berkeleydb offers what you want.